# How to mask image with rounded corners?

Tags: css, image-masking

I want to use image masking or whatever method is best for this .

the shape I want to create is this

[image]

so, how can i accomplish something like this.

i was trying to use clip path for this, but i can only make one round shape from it. i was trying to use another clip path circle with different values to create the other round shape. but it didnt work.

so, how to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Try this https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ using custom polygon by adding tons of "dots"

Comment: i tried using it but somehow wasnt sure how to make it work.

Comment: click custom polygon. then click wherever on the picture on the left

Comment: Gotcha https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/#article-header-id-3

Comment: try this https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/

Comment: thanks. these links look like they could help.

Comment: yes, I was able to do it from reading those links. thanks